# Onclick Pop-up with contact form 7

Tags: javascript, contact-form-7

I have the following codes:

```
<div class="popup" onclick="myFunction()">
    <span style="color: #17304b;">
        <strong><em>Read More</em></strong>
    </span>
    <span class="popuptext" id="myPopup">
        [contact-form-7 id="0001" title="245 Mathews Apartments"]
    </span>
</div>
```

JavaScript:

```
function myFunction() {
    setTimeout(popup, 3000);
    var popup = document.getElementById('myPopup');
    popup.classList.toggle('show');
}
```

However, when it opens the pop-up, it closes again when you click the form to fill up the fields. Can you please help me on this? How to close the pop-up only when you click on the body and not on the form itself?